# Sizing the content to fit into screen resolution

Tags: wpf

hello i have a window(wpf) with labels and text boxes, i want him to fit to the screen resolution as much as possible,
how do i do it

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Viewbox is quite useful if you need the content of your window to scale proportionally when you resize the window (for example maximize it). In this minimalistic page

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Viewbox>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock FontSize="14">Example</TextBlock>
            <Border Background="Aqua" Width="100" Height="100"></Border>                    
        </StackPanel>
    </Viewbox>
</Window>
```

you have a TextBlock and a colored Border stacked vertically; if you start this xaml the window will have a size of 300x300, the font of the TextBlock will be 14 in size and the colored border will be 100x100. If you rescale the window you will see both the TextBlock and the Border scale accordingly (so they'll be no more of the size you've specified in the xaml), keeping relative proportions. Viewbox is really useful, in this respect, if you need a window whose internal components layout look always the same independently from the final resolution it will be displayed (what does matter is aspect-ratio, thought). This obviously work with any contents you'll put inside the Viewbox (we had an application with videos and 3D views for example). Note that in Visual Studio 2008 you'll not be able to see the content of the Viewbox in the Designer.

Hope this help.

Comment: I've been scouring the internet for eternity looking for this <.<

Answer (score 2):

If you want to scale really everything including font sizes, you could probably apply a scale transform to your content, and bind it's X and Y values to the window's width and height. You would then also need a value converter to convert those to the appropriate scale.

Comment: how do i do this in mvvm?
i have a style for all of my vms.. i wanna make the scale..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale everything to the size of the window just put everything inside a Viewbox control.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want the window to fill the entire screen? The simplest way to do that (without causing further headaches) is to maximise the window.

```
w.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
```

EDIT:

A scalable window layout requires you to avoid using the XAML editor in Visual Studio! Actually you can do it in the editor, but it is very hard.

Much easier to write the XAML by hand:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">First Name</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Name="firstName">Fred</TextBox>
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">First Name</Label>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="lastName">Smith</TextBox>
</Grid>
```

This will size to fit the window, though may look strange, as the rows and columns will by default get half the space each. You can override this so they have a height determined by their contents instead:

```
<RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
```

It can also help to put margins on some controls, to space them out:

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Margin="6" Name="lastName">Smith</TextBox>
```

Comment: oh no i wish this was my problem...
i want the content to scale itself to the window size.

Comment: i'm not working with the editor...
u didnt understand me, i want the content to grow... not to spread..

Comment: You're going to have to edit your question, I think. Do you mean you actually want every detail to zoom in, font sizes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Add ***WindowState="Maximized"*** to the Window

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300" WindowState="Maximized" >

</Window>
```