# Resolution Problems C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-interface, layout

I am having issues with sizing my WPF program so that it can adapt to resolution of the user's screen. I have two screenshots below, one is taken at `1600 x 900` and one at `1920 x 1080`. Neither of them are how I want my application to look;

**1600 x 900**
[image]

**1920 x 1080**
[image]

As you can see from the first image, at the lower resolution there are parts of the UI that are just off of the screen. I could use a `ScrollViewer` but I would much prefer for the elements to actually fit the screen vertically and then use a `ScrollViewer` horizontally if neccessary.

In the second image, because I have tried to adapt the program so that it fits the lower resolution, there is now a vast amount of unused space that I would like the UI to fill into, instead of leaving blank. I feel like I have an overall understanding of `*` and `auto` as widths but feel like the general layout is wrong. Here is a snapshot of some XAML for these screenshots;

```
         <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MinWidth="180"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" MaxWidth="160"/>
                <ColumnDefinition />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Rectangle Fill="#FF5FCFBA" Stroke="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Label x:Name="jobTitleLabel" Content="Job" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,10,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="4"/>
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" >
                <Label Content="Reference:" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,0,0,1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="Description:" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="Created:" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,5,0,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <Label Content="Deadline:" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-2,7,0,0" />
                <Label Content="Start Date:" FontSize="14" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="-2,7,0,0" />
                <Label Content="Employee Name:" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,4,0,0" />
                <Label Content="Who's Job:" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,7,0,0" />
                <Label Content="Priority:" FontSize="14" Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,7,0,0" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBox x:Name="jobReferenceTextBox" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="jobTitleTextBox" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" MaxWidth="291" MaxLength="30"/>
                <wpftk:DateTimePicker x:Name="createdPicker" AutoCloseCalendar="True"  
                                      Margin="5,7,5,5" Format="Custom" FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy"
                                      FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Left" 
                                      TimeFormat="LongDate" TimePickerAllowSpin="False" 
                                      TimePickerShowButtonSpinner="False" 
                                      TimePickerVisibility="Hidden" ShowButtonSpinner="False"
                                      AllowTextInput="False"/>
                <wpftk:DateTimePicker x:Name="deadlinePicker" AutoCloseCalendar="True" Margin="5,8,5,5" Format="Custom" FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Left" TimeFormat="LongDate" TimePickerShowButtonSpinner="False" TimePickerAllowSpin="False" TimePickerVisibility="Hidden" ShowButtonSpinner="False"/>
                <wpftk:DateTimePicker x:Name="startDatePicker" AutoCloseCalendar="True" Margin="5,8,5,5" Format="Custom" FormatString="dd/MM/yyyy" FontSize="14" TextAlignment="Left" TimeFormat="LongDate" TimePickerShowButtonSpinner="False" TimePickerAllowSpin="False" TimePickerVisibility="Hidden" ShowButtonSpinner="False"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="nameTextBox" Margin="5,6,5,5" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                <ComboBox x:Name="itNameComboBox" Margin="5,7,5,5" FontSize="14" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Unallocated" Tag="Unallocated"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Adam" Tag="AdamD"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Chris" Tag="Chris"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Dan" Tag="DanD"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Emily" Tag="EmilyC"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Kit" Tag="KitL"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Matt" Tag="Matt"/>
                </ComboBox>
                <ComboBox x:Name="priorityComboBox" Margin="5,7,5,5" FontSize="14" SelectedValuePath="Tag">
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="High" Tag="High"/>
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Medium" Tag="Medium"  />
                    <ComboBoxItem Content="Low" Tag="Low"  />
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1">
                <ComboBox x:Name="jobPresetComboBox" IsEnabled="False" IsEditable="True" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Choose Predefined Job"  Margin="5"  FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" SelectionChanged="JobPresetComboBoxSelectionChanged" />
                <Button x:Name="addJobButton" Content="Add a New Job" Margin="5" Click="AddJob" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" />
                <Button x:Name="updateButton" Content="Update Job Details" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="4" Click="UpdateJob"/>
                <Button x:Name="markAsCompletedButton" Content="Mark as Completed" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Click="MarkAsCompleted"/>
                <Button x:Name="deleteButton" Content="Delete Job" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Click="DeleteJobPermanently"/>
                <Button x:Name="excelButton" Content="Export to Excel" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Click="ExportToExcel"/>
                <Button x:Name="restoreButton" Content="Restore Selected Job" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="RestoreJob"/>
                <Button x:Name="addToHistoryButton" Content="Add to History" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="AddJobToHistory"/>
                <Button x:Name="cancelButton" Content="Cancel Job Add" Margin="5" FontSize="14" Visibility="Collapsed" Click="CancelJobAdd"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBox x:Name="notesTextBox" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Margin="5" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" AcceptsReturn="True" MinHeight="260" MaxHeight="260" MaxWidth="400" MinWidth="400"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <Grid x:Name="bnumGrid" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1" Margin="8,0,10,0" MinWidth="250">
                <DataGrid x:Name="bnumDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentBnumsCollectionView}" MaxHeight="270"
                      CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionChanged="BnumDataGridSelectionChanged"
                      IsReadOnly="True">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job ID" Width="0.75*" Binding="{Binding JobID}"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job Description" Width="3*" Binding="{Binding JobDescription}"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </Grid>
            <StackPanel x:Name="searchGrid" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="5">
                <Label Content="Search (ID)" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,5,0,5" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="20" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                <TextBox x:Name="searchBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="20,5" FontSize="14" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextChanged="CallSearchBoxFilter"/>
                <Label Content="Press Esc to clear filter" Margin="5,10,5,5" FontSize="14"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
```

Understandably there is a lot of irrelevant code included there but I didn't want to miss something out that I am not seeing have an effect. The overall layout is a `NavigationFrame` located inside a `Page` that is located inside a `Window` so that I can navigate through pages on my program.

On this specific page there is a `Grid` with two rows, one containing a DataGrid and one containing the elements in the images above. I am unsure on whether it is the parent `Grid` causing the issues but thought I would post this first just in case there any "obvious" issues with my layout.

Comment: Does this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114385/sizing-the-content-to-fit-into-screen-resolution

Comment: The only problem with a `Viewbox` is that it scales the whole page so your text boxes get bigger/smaller.

Comment: @ChrisF Would there e a suitable alternative to a `ViewBox` then? just wondering before I start testing with it

Comment: @CBreeze there are several different ways - a horizontal `WrapPanel` for example, but each has implications for your design.

Comment: @ChrisF My design specifically or the design of WPF in general?

Comment: @CBreeze Your design. If you use a wrap panel you'll have to lose the grid and your fields won't always be in the same column when the resolution changes. This is bad UX so should really be avoided.

Comment: @ChrisF Would that suggest that my overall idea of a design is poor then?

Comment: @CBreeze - no. The normal solution is to use a scroll viewer or fill the background as appropriate.

Comment: I will tell you why this is happening, you used the designer to create this. If you do the same in code and place these items in xaml yourself you will solve the issue yourself.

Comment: @XAMlMAX actually I didn't use the designer at all.

Comment: So you are responsible for those horrible, horrible Margins. Shame on you. On the serious note it looks to me that your code should perform the scaling without any problems however maybe your `Page` has defined Width or Height. Or even the `NavigationFrame`. I personally use `ContentControl` and then define the `Templates` for each page.

Comment: @XAMlMAX I just couldn't find another way for the `Labels` to line up with the `TextBoxes` :(

Comment: If you have a need for `Labels` I would use `TextBlock`s. From what I see in your `xaml` it seems that you are not using the correct container for them. You should use a `Grid` to make the content fit into the grid. The containers that you are using are not appropriate for what you want to achieve. As Muhammad Bashir said, you need to replace those `StackPanel`s with a `Grid` that would span out across giving you the look that you want.

Comment: @XAMlMAX so you would suggest having each element taking a `Row` of a `Grid` rather than one `StackPanel` occupying a `Column` of the `Grid` like I have done here?

Comment: Rather than using `StackPanel` which will "Stack items", I would use a `Grid` in there which will distribute the items for you. So where you use the `StackPanel` you can replace that with a `Column` of a `Grid`. If that makes sense. I will make an example `xaml` for you to put this into perspective.

Comment: @XAMlMAX that does make sense and thanks for your help. I was just unsure on how the `Grid` would separate out the `TextBlocks` without the use of `Rows`?

Comment: See my answer you should be able to just copy and paste the `xaml`.

Comment: @XAMlMAX sure have! have tried your code and it works ok, looks a bit funny in the designer though and I would like my notes `TextBlock` to have a fixed height and width still so it doesn't grow when the user types into it!

Comment: You mean notes `TextBox` :-) if so then you need to set the `RowSpan` to the max number of Rows in the Grid and then set the ScrollViewer visibility for it to be visible and the `TextWrap` to `WrapWithOverflow`. If my answer helped either accept or upvote, it's nice to be appreciated.

Comment: Honestly I think now you are left with how certain `UIElements` works in `WPF` to get the screen to work as you want. One question what do you mean by "the screen looks weird"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something that I think should give you an idea on how to place items on your screen.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Rectangle Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Grid.RowSpan="6" Fill="Red"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Reference:" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBlock Text="Description:" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />
    <TextBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="5" Text="Mahoosive Text Box" />
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="4"/>
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Button Content="Save New Job" Grid.Column="4" Margin="5" Grid.Row="2" />
    <DataGrid Grid.Column="5" Grid.RowSpan="7">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Job ID"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="6" Text="Search (ID)"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="6" Grid.Row="1" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>

</Grid>
```

As we spoke in comments this is what I meant.
Create a test `UserControl`, paste my code and watch it resize in the designer.

Answer (score 0):

For adoptive redesigning you have go with panel approach. You to add some stack panels and wrap panels to do so. You have to avoid the MARGIN thing and height and width to panels. Well its not an easy topic to close it in one answer.

I can redesign the whole panel for you in 30 to 40 minutes. It would be adoptive then, but i have to use your Team Viewer account and do it in your PC. I have paste the code in my application, but there are a lot of errors and errors. let me know, if you want me to redesign it.